# How to properly type mongoose referenced document in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

The mongoose.Types.ObjectId works fine but I want to better type it using the User Document type, so if I populate it, it will infer the correct type like `profile.user.toObject({getters:true})`. I saw articles using `UserDocument['id']` but it will return `any`. is there a proper way to type this?

```
interface IProfile {
  user: // <- what type to put here (reference to User model)
  bio: string
  jobTitle: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/populate.html) it should work by using `PopulatedDoc`, but as in your case I'm getting `any` as resulting type.